# How to set the reference path for the solution in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a C# solution contains many projects. Each project references some dlls in a specified folder. According to MSDN we could add the reference path for a project in project -> Properties -> Reference Paths. It will generate a .csproj.user file under the project folder with the content below:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ReferencePath>C:\References\bin\</ReferencePath>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

But this only works for one project alone. Is there a simple way to apply the same setting to all of the projects in the solution?

Answer (score 8):

I found a [blog post](http://andsmi.com/post/85237953978/adding-reference-paths-to-all-projects-in-solution) explaining how to do this.

Open the Package Manager Console (e.g. View | Other Windows | Package Manager Console) and use a script such as the following for relative paths:

```
$path = [System.IO.Path]; foreach ($proj in get-project -all) {$proj.Properties.Item("ReferencePath").Value="$($path::GetDirectoryName($proj.filename))\..\libs"}
```

or this for a single fixed project reference for all projects:

```
foreach ($proj in get-project -all) {$proj.Properties.Item("ReferencePath").Value="C:\lib"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is, possibly because Projects can be loaded into many solutions, and if the reference path for required libs becomes scoped to a solution, you'll end up with either build errors, or different behaviours depending on which solution you build the project through if the solutions tell the project to look in different places for dependencies.